# How do I render "cartoon edges" around objects in Blender 3.0?

Tags: rendering, toon-shading

In previous versions of blender it was [possible](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/post_processing/edges.html) to use "toon shaders" in the post-processing render options to render objects with a black outline, as if they'd been drawn around with a pen:

[image: With toon edges]

I have a [blender file](https://easyupload.io/014kkx) that I created in an older version of Blender that I'm now trying to render in 3.0, but the relevant 'edge' options seem to have been removed from the "Output Properties→Post Processing" options.
Ticking the "Freestyle" option to enable the edge options there has no effect.

Have these been moved or removed? What's the simplest way to render an outline without extensive edits to my existing files?

Answer (score 3):

That's freestyle, but may require a lot of tweaks to highlight the edges you want.

[image]

You can edit parameters here

[image]

Comment: I tried enabling freestyle and setting a high line thickness, but this did not affect the render.

Comment: Freestyle is a bit of anarchy. There are a TON of parameters you can monkey with. I added another photo to my answer so you can see where the parameters are. I'd recommend a video or guide somewhere explaining all the different parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen those settings.  I've had a little play but still can't make a line appear... can you suggest settings for a simple black outline?

Comment: You wanna upload your blend file somewhere?

Comment: Uploaded to https://easyupload.io/014kkx